# How to get more speed from my router?

Tags: adsl

DSL RX:12287/TX:1021 (Kbps)
one guy told me that this is the speed the ISP sends to my router, but i only use 2Mb of  12Mb.
So i want to know if exist the possibility to get more speed at least 5Mb.
if need more details just ask.Thanks in advance

Comment: The ADSL speed are shown in bits (12Mbps / 1Mbps). When you download anything, you may see (up to) 1.5MBps / 0.125MBps. Note there I use B (bytes) and b (bits). 8 Bits = 1 Byte. Hence why you see 12Mbps = 1.5MBps. Most PC will interpret download speed in Bytes, as opposed to bits. If you can get a software that shows download speed in bits, you will see the 12Mbps speed. So to answer your question: You can't. That is already the maximum speed. Unless somehow your ISP can add more speed, or you are physically closer to the DSL phone exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, this may be dependent on your ISP, however there may well be things you can do to improve performance.

First off, the  RX:12287/TX:1021 are not the speed which your ISP sends to your router, it is the speed with which the DSL modem inside your router syncs with the equipment on the other end and is a function of the distance from the exchange, the quality of the copper and the quality of the devices on each end.    [ I have built small ISP's, so I am qualified to make this assertion ]

If your ISP is limiting your traffic then you would need to find another ISP. As you have not specified details of your ISP or even country, I can't advise the likelyhood that they are the bottleneck.   If you are in a major city chances are you can detect packet shaping/ISP bottlenecks by running various complex tests on the connection looking for burstability, packet loss and traffic prioritisation.   If you get much better speeds at
certain times it could be an ISP thing.

Assuming the ISP is NOT the bottleneck the following places are likely to be bottlenecks and should be investigated -

1. If you are connecting via WIFI it could well be that your WIFI router is slowing
   things down.  Try moving your devices close to the WIFI router and see if speed 
   improves.   Better yet, bypass the router and use an ethernet cable.
2. Underpowered router - It could be that your routers CPU is under powered - Replacing the
   router would be the correct solution here.  You can to some degree check this by
   connecting only 1 device (and ensuring no other devices are connected) and then running
   a single test of a big file over something like HTTP.  If this gives you an increase
   in speed you know your router is underpowered.
3. Other people using your connection - maybe your WIFI is hacked, maybe a computer,
   maybe someone is torrenting with lots of streams and taking a big piece of the pie.
   Disable WIFI, connect via a cable with only a single computer and see what happens,
   then start switching your stuff back on.

If the problem is that your router is under powered you could try reducing the load on it.  Its difficult to say without knowing what kind of router it is or what protocols you are running, and your options are likely to be quite limited.

Comment: my ISP is Claro Dominicana. my contracted speed is Download:2.5Mb(315-325 KB/S) Upload:1Mb but sometimes it goes crazy at 800 KB/S.So thats what i am asking, how can i have that speed always? @davidgo

Comment: You should not be able to - the correct answer will be to negotiate a better plan with your ISP.   You can probably get 800KB/second for 1 of 2 reasons - 1.  Your ISP has a large "burst" limit so you can burst above your speed for short periods for occasional use - which makes web surfing feel faster, or you are pulling content which is not rate limited by your ISP for various reasons - these could be anything from Not rate limiting traffic to others in their network to others paying to bypass rate limits to misconfigured routing.

Comment: From a purely technical viewpoint you might be able to find someone who you can connect to without the speed limit and who has higher speed, set up a VPN to them and access the Internet through that connection.  Lots of issues doing this though and it could be cheaper and more reliable to just change your plan with your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

- Ask your ISP for more bandwidth.
- Ask a different ISP and if they offer what you want, switch to the new ISP.

Be prepared to pay more in either case, though you can sometimes be pleasantly surprised.